# How to specify Sites in two way anova

Tags: r, anova, hypothesis-testing

```
set.seed(123)

main_levels <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3)
sub_levels <- rep(c("Low", "High"), times = 3)
site_levels <- rep(c("East", "West", "South", "North"), each = 6)

my_dataframe <- data.frame(
  Main = main_levels,
  Sub = sub_levels,
  Site = site_levels
)

print(my_dataframe)

   Main  Sub  Site
1     A  Low  East
2     A High  East
3     A  Low  West
4     A High  West
5     A  Low South
6     A High South
7     B Low  North
8     B High  North
9     B Low  East
10    B High  East
11    B Low  West
12    B High  West
13    B Low South
14    B High South
15    B Low  North
16    B High  North
```

As you can see, I have same level of treatments, same number of replicates at 4 different sites. Now I want to run ANOVA for the results from all sites. So which model would be more appropriate to run

model 1
`aov(response~ Main*Sub*Site, data = my_dataframe)`

model 2
`aov(response ~ Main*Sub+Site, data = my_dataframe)`

model 3
`aov(response~ Main*Sub, data = my_dataframe)`

I tried to run the models, and I was getting different results for all models. I want to see the effects of Main and Sub (and their interactions) but also want to consider data collected from all sites to generalize the results. So which model would be the correct way to consider site in the model?